# Parsing Datetime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following date forma string: `January 5, 2016 07:22am ET`

I would like to be able to parse such date format using DateTime::createFromFormat. I have tried with the following and no success:

```
$new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat($date, 'D d, Y G:i e');
```

where $date is the string  `January 5, 2016 07:22am ET`

Any idea?

Comment: `January` is not a `D` value.... it's a month name, not the short name of a day of the week; perhaps you meant to use `F`

Comment: And `G` means without leading zeroes, and your hours value has leading zeroes

Comment: Nor is there a space between `22` and `am`, but your mask says that one is expected

Comment: Please get a proper documentation on DateTime::createFromFormat
 http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
$date = new DateTime(
    'January 5, 2016 07:22am', //your time string
    new DateTimeZone('UTC') //set you timezone
);
echo $date->format('F d, Y h:ia e');
```

will output

> January 05, 2016 07:22am E

Comment: what timezone this means?

Answer (score 1):

Sets the time zone for the DateTime object

```
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2016-05-27');
 $new_date=$date->format('D d, Y G:i e') ;
 echo $new_date;
```

And Your Output Will Be

> Fri 27, 2016 12:51 UTC

Answer (score 0):

The `ET` is incorrect Timezone word for PHP.

Without that You can create DateTime like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('January 5, 2016 07:22am');
```